# Implement Tkinter GUI form using TopLevel widget

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I am practicing the Tkinter code adopted from following website link:
https://cppsecrets.com/users/839798104105106101101116115105110103104114971065051525364103109971051084699111109/Python-GUI-Registration-Form-Using-Tkinter.php

With the existing code, the Tkinter root window will be destroyed after the 'Submit' button is pressed. I not able to run the code for second time as, there is alarm message "can't invoke wm command application has been destroyed" appear.

I guess the problem is due to the GUI form was created on the main window. Can the issue be solved by using the Tkinter Toplevel() widget? If yes, any suggestion on how to implement it?

Comment: You might want to correspond with the author of that script as your question seems related to debugging his script?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will search around the website to see if there is anyway to get in touch with the author. Do you encounter issue of "can't invoke wm command as application has been destroyed" with Tkinter before? In case you come across any article that can help me on this, feel free to share with me. Thank you

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom of that webpage, it says that to comment you have to Login.. Also you can learn more about Tkinter Top Level from this [site](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html) See item 25.